How to add resources to .resx file in winforms?
I cannot add images to resource.resx in visual studio. when i drag it into resource explorer, the image is just opened. when i click on the "+" sign to add a new resource, a dialog opens. if i try to add the .png file, it auto selects as type a byte array

when i select "system.drawing.bitmap (windows forms)" i get either a target invocation error in error list, or nothing happens at all (no resource is added, no error shown), one of both, that seems to depend on if visual studio runs the resource generation task, but idk. manually starting that task doesnt help either. either way, the resource is not available. this happens when i try to do it in a newly created empty winforms project. what am i doing wrong?
edit: i am aware of workarounds like legacy editor, or reference the file and load it manually etc., however, i search the way to do it idiomatic or the way it is meant to be done with visual studio without workarounds
i need a solution for .net 8 or greater, and the according visual studio versions supported
i am fine with any solution that completes adding an image with the visual studio ui

You can use the "Select Resource" dialog from within a WinForms Form or Control. In the Properties window click on the ellipses (...) of the Image or BackgroundImage property to open it. Then you can choose between "Local Resource" (the Form.resx) or "Project resource file" (Properties\Resources.resx).
In this dialog you can then click on the Import... button to import an image into the resource file:

If you don't need the image in the Form or Control because you want to add it in code, you can then clear the property to leave it empty.

Thank you, but how do i get the image into the resource file in first place? i mean as image, not as byte array as in the picture

You can click the Import button in this dialog window to do it.
